# Triggers vs denormalization

Tags: mysql

I have been wondering what is the deference between triggers and renormalization since both of them cause duplication of data ?
Thank you 
Please a detailed answers

Comment: *what is the deference between triggers and renormalization* You try to compare warm and soft... *both of them cause duplication of data ?* No one of them cause duplication (but may).

Answer (score 2):

A `TRIGGER` gives you a chance to modify what is being `INSERTed/UPDATEd`, or to change some other table based on a modification to the current table.  This usually involves a single row.

"Denormalization" is a specific operation of adding a column to a table and populating it in a certain way.  This usually involves the entire table.

Typically two tables are involved in each, but that is about the only thing they have in common.